# Why this java equals() method violates the symmetric implementation rule?

Tags: java

Following code is a wrong implementation of java equals method. It violated the symmetric rule. But I do not know how it violated this rule. Please point it out where in this method it violated the symmetric rule.

```
public class WrongEquals {

    private final String variable;

    public WrongEquals(String variable) {
            this.variable = variable;
    }

    @override public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (o instanceof String) {
                    return variable.equals((String) o);
            }
            if (o instanceof WrongEquals) {
                    return variable.equals(((WrongEquals) o).variable);
            }
            return false;
    }

    @override
            public int hashCode() {
                    return (variable == null ? 0 : variable.hashCode());
            }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your `WrongEquals` instance can be equal to some `String`, but no `String` will be equal to any instance of `WrongEquals`

Look at the `String` implementation of `equals()` (as of JDK 7)

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String) anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                        return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Obviously this implementation ensures that any equality will only exist between another `String` instance.

Answer (score 4):

(This is just an extension and illustration of Kon's prior answer)

Try adding this main program:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    WrongEquals a = new WrongEquals("xyzzy");
    String b = "xyzzy";
    System.out.println(a.equals(b));
    System.out.println(b.equals(a));
  }
```

It will display:

```
true
false
```